# How can I dynamically change the height of a cardview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm trying to do it with using an objectanimator, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="layout_height"
            android:valueTo="300dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="layout_height"
            android:valueTo="100dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

However, it doesn't work, because as far as I see Cardviews don't have `setHeight`, `setLayoutHeight` nor any other similar methods. So how can I change a card's height ( and similar atributes) then?

Answer (score -1):

Animate the view inside the CardView instead of animating the CardView itself.

Comment: Inside the card I have a RelativeLayout containing several textviews. I try applying android:stateListAnimator="@anim/elevar_tarjeta" and 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"to the relativelayout, but it doesnt work because "Method setLayout_height() with type float not found on target class class android.widget.RelativeLayout" (that is, the layout doesn't have a setheight method either it seems).

Comment: Which child of you RelativeLayout is supposed to get the extra height you want to add to the card ? Are your CardView or RelativeLayout have a fixed height or a wrap_content height ?

Comment: the extra height is supposed to be spread between the elements inside the layout, I don't one one of them to take the whole increase specifically . My cardview has a wrap_content height, and my layout's layout_height is set at a fixed height (100dp).